# How to make footer image jump above mobile keypad

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I have a footer image which on click returns to the home page.
However, the image shall always be visible. So when the mobile keypad appears the image shall jump above the keypad.

Any idea how to do this?

[image]

EDITED :

Here is the directive I tired, but the image doesn't move upwards when the mobile keypad appears. The keypad hides the image:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('TestApp')
    .directive('stickyText', ['$mdSticky', stickyText]);

function stickyText($mdSticky) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<span style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;"> <img src="assets/img/icons/home.png" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> </span>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $mdSticky(scope, element);
        }
    }
}

})();
```

HTML code:

```
<sticky-text ui-sref="home"> </sticky-text>
```

Comment: can you share css code for that ?

Comment: I agree with @Rocky, we need to see what CSS you have at the moment.

Comment: Hello, I added the directive I  wrote for the sticky image. The CSS only includes "position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;" to position the image at the bottom right

Comment: instead bottom:0 try with top:0

Comment: @ABUdhay : It's a footer image. I need the image at the bottom. Placing top:0 will move the image at the top.

Comment: then wrap the span with top:0 into a div with position:relative;bottom:0;right:0 ..

Comment: @ABUdhay : I tired but the mobile keyboard still hides the image when it appears:
            <footer style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
                <span style="top:0;">
               <img src="assets/img/icons/thumb_home.png" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> 
                </span>
            </footer>

Comment: <footer style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;"> <span style="position: absolute; right: 0; top:0;"> <img src="assets/img/icons/thumb_home.png" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> </span> </footer>  try this .. if keypad is appending in the footer div it will work fine.. if it is replacing it won't

Comment: The keypad on mobile still covers the footer image when it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to move the footer above the keyboard with the following jquery:

```
    $('form').on('focus', 'input, textarea', function() {
        $("footer").addClass('aboveKeyboard'); 
    });

    $('form').on('blur', 'input, textarea', function() {
        $("footer").removeClass('aboveKeyboard'); 
    });
```

CSS:

```
.aboveKeyboard img{
top :30%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer ui-sref="homepg">
    <img src="thumb_home.png" style="position: absolute; right: 0;bottom: 0;"> 
</footer>
```